# facing "Microsoft .NET framework unhandled exception has occurred in your application" error when trying to open an application using pywinauto

Tags: python, jit, pywinauto

I am trying to automate an application using python "pywinauto" library, but when I run the code I face the "Microsoft .NET framework unhandled exception has occurred in your application" error. however, when I open the application without code, it opens with no error!

here are the details of error:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYKqK.png)

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.ApplicationException: Usage: mstop <instrument-number>, <macro>, <start-macro-file>
   at MSTop.FormMSTop.InitializeCommandProcessor() in E:\ccviews\Mustang\Mustang\parts\mstop.net\FormMSTop.cs:line 44
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

************** Loaded Assemblies **************

```
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8745 (WinRel.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MSTop
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/msdchem/MSexe/mstop.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8745 (WinRel.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8745 (WinRel.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8745 (WinRel.050727-8700)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
HIACPNet
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/msdchem/MSexe/HIACPNet.DLL
----------------------------------------
MSDChemCPUtil
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/msdchem/MSexe/MSDChemCPUtil.DLL
```

---

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: How do you call the application? The error contains a usage message. Are you sure the arguments you use are correct?

Comment: Usually it is application issue. But if you're not testing the app and you have no chance to fix it on app side, I can suggest using `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` to let the application staff to be lazy initialized before automating next steps. Let me know if it works.